# Using the delta method to find the asymptotic distribution

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, normal-distribution, delta-method

**The Question:**

Given independent random variables $X_1, \dots,X_n \sim N(\mu,\mu^2)$, let $Q=\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline X)^2$ where $\overline X = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Use the delta method to find the asymptotic distribution of $\frac 13\Bigl(\overline X+2\sqrt{\frac{Q}{n-1}}\Bigr)$.

---

**My Thoughts:**

I understand how to use the delta method to find the asymptotic distribution for any function of only $\overline X$, but this is clearly not the case for $Q$.

Also, I suppose you can't let $Y_i=(X_i-\overline X)^2$ and then apply delta method with $\overline Y$ because the $Y_i$ are not independent. So, is the following approach correct?

Let $g(u)=\sqrt u$ (so $g'(u)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt u}$).

We know that $R:=\frac{1}{\mu^2}Q \sim \chi_{n-1}^2$, so

\begin{align}
\ & \Bbb E (R)=n-1 \; \; \; \text{ and } \; \; \; \operatorname{Var}(R)=2(n-1) \\
\ \implies & g(R)=\sqrt R \approx N \biggl(g(\Bbb E(R)) \; , \; g'(\Bbb E (R))^2 \operatorname{Var}(R) \biggr)=N \Bigl(\sqrt{n-1} \; , \; \frac 12 \Bigr) \\
\ \implies & \sqrt Q = \mu\sqrt R \approx N \Bigl(\mu\sqrt{n-1} \; , \; \frac {\mu^2}{2}\Bigr)
\end{align}

Mainly, I am not sure if we need to divide by $n$ in the asymptotic variance.

Comment: I'm not sure that dependency between random variables is a problem in delta method.

Comment: Do you know that $Q$ (up to a $N-1$ factor) is a classical random variable called "sample variance" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Is there some important property about it that I should be aware of?

Comment: @User112358 I thought the proof of the delta method relied on the CLT which requires independence?

Comment: With the interpretation I just gave you (sample variance), I consider your problem **intuitively** as asymptotically studying variations of $(mean+2\sigma)/3=(\mu+2\mu)/3=\mu$. Thus I would bet that you asymptoticaly obtain a dirac measure centered in $\mu$...